# Is it possible to have a Listview.seperated without having to use a itembuilder?

Tags: flutter

I want to have a Listview.seperated where I can define the elements as children instead of using the itembuilder. I found a way in the code I posted below which allows me to sort of insert it as if is a children array. But this way I have to manually change the item count. Is there any other way without having to store the array somewhere in a field?

```
child: ListView.separated
(
  itemCount: 3,
  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(height: 1.0), 
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index)
  {
    [
      ListTile(
        title: Text('Group Name'),
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: Text('Leave Group'),
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: Text('Invite Member'),
      )
    ][index];
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have a Listview.seperated without having to use a
>   itembuilder?

The answer is **no**, because:

```
ListView.separated constructor
ListView.separated(
{Key key,
Axis scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
bool reverse: false,
ScrollController controller,
bool primary,
ScrollPhysics physics,
bool shrinkWrap: false,
EdgeInsetsGeometry padding,
@required IndexedWidgetBuilder itemBuilder,
@required IndexedWidgetBuilder separatorBuilder,
@required int itemCount,
bool addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
bool addRepaintBoundaries: true,
bool addSemanticIndexes: true,
double cacheExtent}
)
```

this is the part that you are interested in:

```
@required IndexedWidgetBuilder itemBuilder,
@required IndexedWidgetBuilder separatorBuilder,
@required int itemCount,
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.separated.html